# Open FB.ui in a lightbox instead of popup

Tags: javascript, facebook

What I do now:

```
FB.ui(
    {
        method: 'stream.share',
        display: 'iframe',
        u: url
    },
    function (response) {
        //console.log(response);
    }
);
```

This is exactly what I need, but it opens a popup instead of a nice lightbox like window.

Answer (score 0):

Use method `feed` instead of `stream.publish`. Example code:

```
var share = {
    method: "feed",
    name: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet!",
    link: "http://www.google.com/",
    picture: "http://placekitten.com/95/95",
    caption: "Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus.",
    description: "Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram."
};

FB.ui(share, function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
        console.log("Callback for FB share:", response);
    } else {
        console.log("Share was not made.");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. When you call `FB.init` make sure to set `status: true`. There is some information about it on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.2

Setting `status: true` tries to get information about the user at login. I guess if the user is known before calling `FB.ui` it will use the dialog versus the popup. I'm able to see the dialog for desktop apps, but not mobile which I believe is by design.